# jCrop - update preview onload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jcrop

I am using the jCrop preview demo to do my own thing. However I have run into a problem. If I create a default selection when the image loads using `setSelect:` then I have the selection mapped out on the big image but it doesn't appear on the preview. I cannot find an api handler to call the updatePreview function when jCrop loads. Does anyone know how to call this function when jCrop loads?

```
jQuery(function($){

      // Create variables (in this scope) to hold the API and image size
      var jcrop_api, boundx, boundy;

      $('#target').Jcrop({
        onChange: updatePreview,
        onSelect: updatePreview,
        setSelect: [ 0, 0, selectWidth, selectHeight ],
        aspectRatio: 1
      },function(){
        // Use the API to get the real image size
        var bounds = this.getBounds();
        boundx = bounds[0];
        boundy = bounds[1];
        // Store the API in the jcrop_api variable
        jcrop_api = this;
      });

      function updatePreview(c)
      {
        if (parseInt(c.w) > 0)
        {
          var rx = 100 / c.w;
          var ry = 100 / c.h;

          $('#preview').css({
            width: Math.round(rx * boundx) + 'px',
            height: Math.round(ry * boundy) + 'px',
            marginLeft: '-' + Math.round(rx * c.x) + 'px',
            marginTop: '-' + Math.round(ry * c.y) + 'px'
          });
        }
      };

    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to set the default value and the default value is getting previewed in the preview box.

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){

            jQuery('#cropbox').Jcrop({
                onChange: showPreview,
                onSelect: showPreview,
                setSelect: [ 100, 0, 100, 100 ],
                aspectRatio: 1
            });

        });
```

This just worked the way i wanted. You might have some other error on your script. But you dont have to invoke anything special to have to show the preview. If you are not doing this onload then try doing it onload.

Comment: Well shiver me timbers. Thats annoying. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 8):

Rather than the animateTo hack, you can just set the initial selection in the callback. So:

```
$('#target').Jcrop({
    onChange: updatePreview,
    onSelect: updatePreview,
    aspectRatio: 1
  },function(){
    // Use the API to get the real image size
    var bounds = this.getBounds();
    boundx = bounds[0];
    boundy = bounds[1];
    // Store the API in the jcrop_api variable
    jcrop_api = this;
    jcrop_api.setSelect([ 0, 0, selectWidth, selectHeight ]); // <--
  });
```

Comment: Forever grateful!  Exactly what I was searching the web for!

Answer (score 5):

I couldn't get this to work either and found your question searching for a solution myself.

I'm using the preview demo (tutorial3) in Jcrop v0.9.9.

Changed `jQuery(function($){` to `jQuery(window).load(function(){`

And added the option `setSelect: [ 0, 40, 312, 244 ]`

And, it doesn't update the preview on load..

The workaround I've found is to use the api `animateTo` as well as `setSelect` (or on it's own if you like the animation, the speed of which you can change with the option `swingSpeed`)

I've made the change in your code

```
jQuery(function($){

  // Create variables (in this scope) to hold the API and image size
  var jcrop_api, boundx, boundy;

  $('#target').Jcrop({
    onChange: updatePreview,
    onSelect: updatePreview,
    setSelect: [ 0, 0, selectWidth, selectHeight ],
    aspectRatio: 1
  },function(){
    // Use the API to get the real image size
    var bounds = this.getBounds();
    boundx = bounds[0];
    boundy = bounds[1];
    // Store the API in the jcrop_api variable
    jcrop_api = this;
    jcrop_api.animateTo([ 0, 0, selectWidth, selectHeight ]);
  });

  function updatePreview(c)
  {
    if (parseInt(c.w) > 0)
    {
      var rx = 100 / c.w;
      var ry = 100 / c.h;

      $('#preview').css({
        width: Math.round(rx * boundx) + 'px',
        height: Math.round(ry * boundy) + 'px',
        marginLeft: '-' + Math.round(rx * c.x) + 'px',
        marginTop: '-' + Math.round(ry * c.y) + 'px'
      });
    }
  };

});
```

Comment: this appears to be the only listed answer that actually solves the problem entirely (updates the preview correctly and also invokes the onChange callbacks so that the calling code knows what initial rectangle JCrop chose -- since it will actually modify the coords you pass into setCoords/animateTo if they don't match the aspect ratio or fit the image)